# How to pass 2 parameters in for loop in django templates

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

i want to pass 2 parameters in for loop in my template

```
{% for x, y in text %}

  <p>{{ x }}</p><h1>{{ y }}</h1>

{% endfor %}
```

my views:

```
text = [("e", "w"), ("1", "2")]
return render(request, "my_template.html", {"text": text})
```

this isn't even loop and it does absolute nothing

what I need to write in the template or in "text" to make this work?

Comment: This is your *entire* template? Or did you use tempalte inheritance?

Comment: no it's not its just 2 lines from the tamplate

Comment: are you sure that this part of the template *renders* anyway? Due to template inheritance/if conditions, etc. not all parts will be rendered per se.

Comment: sorry i dont understand you can you explain?

Comment: Add a debug line (such as `Text: "{{ text }}"`) before the `for` loop to see if there is anything wrong with the context variable.

Comment: Your code should works! Try to render a simple str as `{"text":"simple string"}` and see if you can render it

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for item in text %}

  <p>{{ item }}</p><h1>{{ item }}</h1>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry i had
`[("e", "w", "q"), ("1", "2", "3")]`
this is the error i had.
how can i close this question?